# Allowing commas in decimal values using Fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidation to validate data in my MVC project.  I have a decimal value that I am entering on a page, but if a comma is included in it then validation fails for it.  For example "12,000.00".  How can I get FluentValidation to accept such values?

Comment: You could try a regex validator.  Regex example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1566016/2181514

Comment: After you solve problem with validation, model-binding problem can become actual http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520005/problem-with-double-values-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by creating a custom binder for decimal values.  This should work regardless of what validation tool you're using.  See this link on how to do that:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/