# Fluent Validation not accepting numbers with thousands separator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Fluent Validation for MVC 5. I am also using a jQuery masking plugin to automatically add thousands to double values.

In the model I have:

```
    [Display(Name = "Turnover")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,ConvertEmptyStringToNull =true,DataFormatString ="#,##0")]
    public double? Turnover { get; set; }
```

In the view I have:

```
<th class="col-xs-2">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Turnover)
</th>
<td class="col-xs-4">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Turnover, new { @class = "form-control number", placeholder="Enter number. Thousands added automatically" })
</td>
<td class="col-xs-6">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Turnover, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</td>
```

A fluent validator is defined for the containing model but it contains no rules. I am using server side validation only.

```
public class MyModelValidator: AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelValidator()
    {

    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get a validation error for turnover as follows:
[image]

I have tried using [Model Binding](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/) to solve this problem. But the break point in model binder never gets hit - fluent validation seems to block the value from reaching the model binder.

Comment: Have you considered changing the type to string and then using a backing field that is a double, then having the getter and setter do the coversion for you? I feel like there is a better way to handle it like you would using a converter in XAML apps, but I'm not sure how to do it in this context... or float something off of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975128/asp-net-mvc-data-annotation-for-currency-format

Comment: Where is your FluentValidation for your model? Is the error from `ModelState`, or does your AbstractValidator cause the error?

Comment: I've added the code for the empty validator

Comment: When you say _I am using server side validation only_ - have you actually disabled client side validation? If you have not specifically disabled it, then `jquery.validate.js` would prevent the for being submitted.

Comment: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` looks suspicious - why you're using client-side validation besides server-side validation? The `Turnover` property declared as `Nullable<double>` which accepts number value without thousand separator, you need to set client-side formatting without altering field value using JS or remove client-side validation for corresponding property.

Comment: Might be culture related issue. What is your Thread Culture? Also verify the decimal separator of your culture is `,` - `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`

Answer (score 5):

Few things to mention:

- The issue has nothing in common with Fluent Validation. I was able to reproduce/fix it with or without Fluent Validation.
- The `DataFormatString` used is incorrect (missing the value placeholder). It should really be `"{0:#,##0}"`.
- The `ModelBinder` approach from the [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/) actually works. I guess you forgot that it is written for `decimal` data type, while your model is using `double?`, so you have to write and register another one for `double` and `double?` types.

Now on the subject. There are actually two solutions. Both of them use the following helper class for the actual string conversion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

public static class NumericValueParser
{
    static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<string, CultureInfo, object>> parsers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, CultureInfo, object>>
    {
        { typeof(byte), (s, c) => byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(sbyte), (s, c) => sbyte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(short), (s, c) => short.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(ushort), (s, c) => ushort.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(int), (s, c) => int.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(uint), (s, c) => uint.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(long), (s, c) => long.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(ulong), (s, c) => ulong.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(float), (s, c) => float.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(double), (s, c) => double.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
        { typeof(decimal), (s, c) => decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, c) },
    };

    public static IEnumerable<Type> Types { get { return parsers.Keys; } }

    public static object Parse(string value, Type type, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return parsers[type](value, culture);
    }
}
```

**Custom `IModelBinder`**

This is a modified version of the linked approach. It's a single class that handles all the numeric types and their respective nullable types:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class NumericValueBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var binder = new NumericValueBinder();
        foreach (var type in NumericValueParser.Types)
        {
            // Register for both type and nullable type
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(type, binder);
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type), binder);
        }
    }

    private NumericValueBinder() { }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
        {
            try
            {
                var type = bindingContext.ModelType;
                var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
                var valueType = underlyingType ?? type;
                actualValue = NumericValueParser.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, valueType, valueResult.Culture);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }
        }
        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

All you need is to register it in your `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    NumericValueBinder.Register();  
    // ...
}
```

**Custom `TypeConverter`**

This is not specific to ASP.NET MVC 5, but `DefaultModelBinder` delegates string conversion to the associated [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) (similar to other NET UI frameworks). In fact the issue is caused by the fact that the default `TypeConverter` classes for numeric types do not use `Convert` class, but `Parse` overloads with [`NumberStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) passing `NumberStyles.Float` which excludes `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`.

Fortunately `System.ComponentModel` provides extensible [Type Descriptor Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx) which allows you to associate a custom `TypeConverter`. The plumbing part is a bit complicated (you have to register a custom [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx) in order to provide [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) implementation that finally returns custom `TypeConverter`), but with the help of the provided base classes that delegate most of the stuff to the underlying object, the implementation looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

class NumericTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        foreach (var type in NumericValueParser.Types)
            TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new NumericTypeDescriptionProvider(type, TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(type)), type);
    }

    readonly Descriptor descriptor;

    private NumericTypeDescriptionProvider(Type type, TypeDescriptionProvider baseProvider)
        : base(baseProvider)
    {
        descriptor = new Descriptor(type, baseProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(type));
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return descriptor;
    }

    class Descriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        readonly Converter converter;
        public Descriptor(Type type, ICustomTypeDescriptor baseDescriptor)
            : base(baseDescriptor)
        {
            converter = new Converter(type, baseDescriptor.GetConverter());
        }
        public override TypeConverter GetConverter()
        {
            return converter;
        }
    }

    class Converter : TypeConverter
    {
        readonly Type type;
        readonly TypeConverter baseConverter;
        public Converter(Type type, TypeConverter baseConverter)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.baseConverter = baseConverter;
        }
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return baseConverter.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            return baseConverter.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return baseConverter.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }
        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                try { return NumericValueParser.Parse((string)value, type, culture); }
                catch { }
            }
            return baseConverter.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
    }
}
```

(Yeah, a lot of boilerplate code in order to add one essential line! From the other side, there is no need to handle nullable types because `DefaultModelBinder` already does that :)

Similar to the first approach, all you need is to register it:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    NumericTypeDescriptionProvider.Register();  
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried all these techniques and could not get any to work with FluentValidation. But for the detail I think half the bounty is appropriate. I think FluentValidation needs changing with a pull request.

Comment: No problem, I don't care for bounties. But really sad to hear the issue is not resolved. I installed FluentValidation package and set it up, didn't see any difference in that regard. W/o the above hooks, the issue is duplicated. With them - fixed. May be there is something else involved - for instance, if I use `EditorFor`, the above fixes does not work for `int` and similar (but work for `decimal`, `double` and `float`). But `TextBoxFor` works for all types. May be that's a clue, I don't know. Will be watching, please post if you find the cause/solution. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - that might be it - need to switch EditorFor to TextBoxFor for.

Comment: I now have this working. I owe you 125 points for the bounty but there does not appear to be a way for me to give this to you ...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with FluentValidation, but MVC's model binding to `double` type. MVC's default model binder cannot parse the number and assigns `false` to `IsValid`.

The problem was solved after I included the following code, [credits to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530633/2346893).

```
public class DoubleModelBinder : System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder {
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.AttemptedValue)
            && (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(double) || bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(double?))) {
            double temp;
            if (double.TryParse(result.AttemptedValue, out temp)) return temp;
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And include the lines below in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double), new DoubleModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double?), new DoubleModelBinder());
```

Also consider explicitly stating the current culture as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16058958/2346893).

Comment: Works but not with integers

Comment: @gls123 Duh, you have to write another class for `int` and `int?` and add it to model binders.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a culture issue. Try use dot instead of a comma on a client side (10,000,000 -> 10.000.000) or fix culture issue on server side.