# Automatical bind of datetime fields in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, data-binding, model

I have a page with many date fields, which can be dynamically added on client side. I have a DatTime? property on editor template for this field:

```
[Display(Name = "Bar Admission Date")]
public DateTime? AdmissionDate { get; set; }
```

When I'm submitting a form I get a null data in AdmissionDate field because binder doesn't know the format of the field.

I have 2 ideas of how t oovercome this issue:

1. Make a string field in model and parse it on a server side. Simple and pretty quick.
2. Write a custom model binder for date fields. I don't like this solution because I don't know the keys for all fields that I will use.

Is there better solution? I searched how can I overload TextboxFor method in order to pass it a culture, but I didn't find

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use an enumerable (IList/ICollection) of `DateTime?`.  [Phil Haacked has a good article on model binding to a list (even when the number of items is dynamic)](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

**Updated**

As for the formatting problem, I would look at how to [set the culture for the project/model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050641/asp-net-mvc-model-binder-with-global-number-formats).

Comment: thanks, already saw his article. the issue is only in the date format. Don't see this covered in the article